# Finding the largest polyominoes that can fit in a rectangular space

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics, packing-problem, polyomino

I am making a program that generates $3$ random polyominoes of size $x \le n$ (referring to the number of squares in the shape). Each polyomino fits within a space: $k \times k$ *($k=6$ in my case).*

I am trying to determine the maximum value of $n$ where all 3 polyominoes are guaranteed to fit in a space of size $L \times M$. For this problem, the pieces can be rotated, but not mirrored.

*(for my current case: $L=M=8$)*

In this [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0oDw.png) $n=10$ with the worst case $x = n$ for all 3 pieces. As you can see, there exists at least 1 [solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtckt.png).

Comment: The green piece in your example is a cross with arms of lengths 1, 2, 3, 3. If you instead take a cross piece with arms lengths 2,2,2,3 then three of those will not fit into an 8x8 square. So for $L=M=8$ the value of $n$ is smaller than $10$. If you limit your piece size to $9$, they will likely be very easy to fit into the $L\times M$ board. Limiting  the size of the pieces to the very unlikely worst case won't make for challenging puzzles. Maybe just check solvability or else generate the random polyominoes in situ on the board to ensure a solution.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I realize that the question I gave is an incomplete description of the entire game. My system will be placing the pieces within the $L \times M$ board. The game that players actually play is matching the pieces in the board to a larger amount of pieces outside the square. So the challenge here is simply ensuring that the placement system can always work with the pieces it is given. If the worst case is unacceptably small, I'll just have to find a workaround, such as scrapping the current puzzle.